# criando um grupo de numeros aleatorios que seja unico

Tags: php

Existe o uniqid para criar um grupo unico de caracteres, porem essa função usa letras e números. E já pesquisei, só que não achei nada pra apenas números. Alguém sabe algum modo de realizar isso?

Comment: Você quer isso? [`rand()`](http://br2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php) ou [`mt_rand()`](http://br2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: Ja tentei usar esse mt_rand so que toda hora da erro

Comment: esse rand já ajuda. Mas tem como evitar que o numero gerado nao se repita?

Comment: Especifique suas tentativas na pergunta, incluindo o erro que você enfrentou com o `mt_rand()`. [edit] pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tudo depende do que você quer dizer com "únicos" e o que fará com esses números. Em pricípio, o uniqid() retorna valores em hexa que você pode converter para decimais:

```
$uid = hexdec(uniqid());
```

Uma outra solução seria esta:

```
$digitos = '0123456789';
$tamanho = 16; // por exemplo...
$uid = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $tamanho; $i++) {
    $uid .= $digitos[rand(0, strlen($digitos) - 1)];
}
```

(Solução baseada [neste código](http://codepad.org/eukiOb6S%20neste%20c%C3%B3digo))

O resultado seria uma string numérica aleatória com 16 dígitos, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `microtime`

> microtime — Retorna um timestamp Unix com microsegundos

Dependendo da finalidade pode ser uma alternativa simples e viável e com baixo risco de colisão.

```
echo microtime();
0.97959400 1407273578
```

Você pode remover o . e o espaço

Answer (score 1):

basta ir incluindo os números em um array, checando antes se já não existe nele.

```
$sorteados = array();

for($i = 0; $i <= 1000; ++$i) {
    do {
       $nr = rand(1000,10000);
    } while (in_array($nr,$sorteados));
    $sorteados[] = $nr;
}

print_r($sorteados);
```